# Converting a php object to javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a selectAll function which returns the results as objects.

```
$customers = $app['database']->selectAll('customers');
```

Here is the var_dump for $customers variable just in case:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> object(stdClass)#5 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "10" ["name"]=> string(10) "Thisted El" ["address"]=> string(13) "Otto Monsteds" ["city"]=> string(5) "Vej 8" ["phone"]=> string(9) "503982350" ["zip"]=> string(6) "481922" ["notes"]=> string(0) "" } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#6 (7) { ["id"]=> string(2) "11" ["name"]=> string(11) "Bibin Vinod" ["address"]=> string(8) "Kottayam" ["city"]=> string(5) "Kochi" ["phone"]=> string(10) "0294294022" ["zip"]=> string(6) "129042" ["notes"]=> string(0) "" }
}
```

I need to use the 'name' property of these objects for an auto-fill form. I am using the autocomplete script in [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp).

In my php file, I have added the above autofill function after the form. Then I use json_encode on this object followed by JSON.parse. I use a loop to add just the names to a javascript array, and finally I pass it to the autocomplete function.

```
var js_data = '<?php echo json_encode($customers); ?>';

var js_obj = JSON.parse(js_data);

for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) 
{
   customername[i] = js_obj["name"];
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("customers"), customername);
```

However the autofill form is not working. I'd like help regarding this issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can simplify the first two lines to `var js_obj = <?php echo json_encode($customers) ?>;`

Comment: Did you use this site to create your autocompleet? https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_autocomplete . Could you post your code of your form, with the input field you want to make autocomplete? Also did you debug your code, does customername have values in it?

Comment: Yes I used that link for my autocomplete. Here is the relevant part of the form:

                    `<form  autocomplete="off" method = "POST" action = "database/NewProduct.php">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="autocomplete form-group col-md-3">
                                <label>Customer</label>
                                <input id="customers" class ="form-control" type="text" name="customers" id="customers" placeholder="Search..">
                            </div></div>`

customername is a null array when I debug.

Comment: So as I understand the problem lies within the for loop since the array customername is not getting filled properly.

Comment: yup that will be the problem. Also I see in your code that your input has 2id's delete one. The problem is going to be that you didn't stick to the sites functions. your for loop is not in the function autocomplete. you should read and understand the site example. your for loop needs to be in a function called autocomplete (the function you call at the end) and instead of arrayLength its probably going to be customername.length as customername is your array. Hope this helps

Comment: I have deleted one id. I do not understand why the loop needs to be inside the function since it'll be parsed either way. Also, then the function call to autocomplete wouldn't work either since the scope of variable customername will be limited to inside the function right?

Comment: hmm it's pretty hard to tell without knowing all the code. But if I look at it again I think that you need to do a foreach of jd_obj to get all the names?

Comment: Here you can see most of the code: https://pastebin.com/SzGZ9KBU The formatting is slightly off but you should be able to identify the relevant portions. I don't see how a foreach will do anything different in this case.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. First off all you have 2 different codes. in your link you have `var js_obj = <?php echo json_encode($customers) ?>;
 
var customername = [];`
While above you also have the JSON.parse. So please also include the JSON.Parse in your code and try again. If this does not works, could you check what value you have in your js_obj variable?

Comment: I do not think JSON.parse is required as it seems parsed to an object already. It does not work when I add it (code: https://pastebin.com/yZGCXUW6) The error can be seen in my reply to Barmar's answer in the comments.

Comment: ok, did you check if your js_obj has data in it?

Comment: Yes this is the console.log for js_data :
`Object { id: "13", name: "ELTECHNO", address: "Knosgaardsvej", city: "aabybro", phone: "20202020", zip: "9250", notes: "ELinstallatror" }`
It seems I cannot use .length function to find it's length, or indices to access each element.

Comment: ahh, maybe it's possible to do something like js_obj["name"].length? Like to get all the names in an array and take the length of that than it should work I think.

Comment: That seems to have partially fixed it! But there are still some problems. when I use json_encode, only the first object is getting parsed, the one in my comment above starting with id: 13. The other objects are not getting parsed. The php variable $customers contains the entire array of objects but only the last one is getting stored to the javascript array.

Comment: for the last problem, you probably have to also use a loop to store all data in the array otherwise its just going to overwrite it I think, the parse problem I don't know. But maybe now that the autocomplete is solved it might be a good idea to try a bit yourself and if you get stuck ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will dig around a bit and see if I can fix it. One tiny small question if you don't mind, once I have everything in the js_data array, how do I parse through it? `js_data["name"][i];` simply goes through each letter of the 'name' property in the first object.

Comment: I have fixed it. Thanks a lot @mrdeadsven

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure, but my best guess would be that you don't have a head element for your JSON. So normally it would look like for example `{"customers":[{"id" : "1", "name" : "aaa"},{"id" : "2", "name" : "bbb"}]}` if you have a JSON like this the parse will also only go through the first element but here that is the header "customers" so it will take everything inside of it. So I get the feeling that your JSON might need a header in order to work properly. But I'm not sure since I don't know everything about JSON

Comment: @mrdeadsven Thanks, it seems the problem was, I had to convert to first convert the php object array to a normal array. Check my answer to see my solution. Thanks a lot for your assistance. It' very much appreciated!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the problem. First I converted the object array to a normal array in PHP:

```
$customers = $app['database']->selectAll('customers');

$allCustomers = array();

foreach($customers as $key => $val) 
{
    $allCustomers[] = $val;
}
```

Then in the javascript part, I used `json encode` on this variable, and used a for loop to add each 'name' property to a javascript array, and finally passed it to the autocomplete function likewise:

```
var js_data = <?php echo json_encode($allCustomers) ?>;

var customername = [];

for (var i = 0; i < js_data.length; i++) 
{
    customername[i] = js_data[i]["name"];
}

autocomplete(document.getElementById("customers"), customername);
```

Thanks a lot everyone for offering your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you simply need to change the input value instead of the div DOM

```
document.getElementById("customers").value = customername;
```

Comment: I do not think this works as I need to use the autocomplete function which lists down suggestions based on what I type in from this array.

Comment: there is different answer to this, but it can work you just have to replace the good DOM element. And if you check the function in your link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_autocomplete.asp he creates a div with the new list. So just regenerate your list and append it at the right place ;)

Answer (score 0):

`js_obj` is an array, you need to index it.

```
customername[i] = js_obj[i].name;
```

You could also just create an array of names in PHP.

```
$customers = array_map(function($x) {
    return $x->name;
}, $app['database']->selectAll('customers'));

?>
var customers = <?php echo json_encode($customers; ?>;
```

Comment: Thanks. I have made this change, but it still does not work. I have also modified the code in the original post.

Comment: Don't modify the code in the original post, then my answer makes no sense.

Comment: Sorry, I did not think about that, I shall keep that in mind next time I post. The console output is as follows:
`Object { id: "13", name: "ELTECHNO", address: "Knosgaardsvej", city: "aabybro", phone: "20202020", zip: "9250", notes: "ELinstallatror" } newProduct.php:261:1`

Comment: Just to clarify, if I simply create a string array and pass it to the autocomplete function, it is working. So I think it has something to do with the way I'm converting it.

Comment: Correction to my above comment, from the comments on the original post, it seems the problem is within the for loop as the array is not getting filled properly.

Comment: I don't understand why `js_obj` is an object, not an array of objects. `$customers` was an array in PHP, so `json_encode()` should create a Javascript array.

Comment: As I understand, only when I use JSON.parse will the data be converted to a javascript object, output of json_encode is not an object or an array.  
`var js_data = {"id":"13","name":"ELTECHNO","address":"Knosgaardsvej","city":"aabybro","phone":"20202020","zip":"9250","notes":"ELinstallatror"};
   var js_obj = JSON.parse(js_data);`
This is the console output. It seems there is some trouble parsing it since I also get an error:
`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data[Learn More]`
So I do not need to parse it again if I understand this correctly.

Comment: I removed the JSON.parse line. I think I cannot use .length function on the js_data object. I put `i < 1000` as the condition and now at least it's entering the loop. Now the console throws an error `TypeError: js_data[i] is undefined[Learn More]` from inside the array.